# How do I programmatically disable a filter from a text format?

Tags: input-formats, 10

Suppose I have a text format like `full_html` and I have an enabled filter with ID `my_filter_id`.

How can I disable the filter programmatically from `full_html`.

I needed to put this in an update hook.

Hopefully its a one-liner.

Answer (score 0):

I did find a solution thought it wasn't a one liner. This will remove the filter from all text formats.

```
use Drupal\filter\Entity\FilterFormat;

function MYMODULE_update_10000(&$sandbox) {
  $filters = filter_formats();
  foreach ($filters as $name => $filter) {

    /* @var $filter Drupal\filter\Entity\FilterFormat */
    // Instantiate the filter collection prior to removing the filters to
    // avoid fatal errors.
    $filter->filters();
    $filter->removeFilter('my_filter_id');
    $filter->save();
  }

}
```

I found the solution from [Drupal.org](https://www.drupal.org/project/glossify/issues/3244714)